# Automatically Expand a Drop-Down List

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have a cell with drop-down list in it. I manually press the down arrow (on the right of the cell) to show the content of the list. I need a way to automatically expand the list using VBA. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically expand the list"?  Do you mean visually so you can see more options on screen or did you need to be able to add more options to the list?

Comment: Yes, I just need it to visually expand the list so you can see the options instead of manually clicking the down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below codes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Validation.InCellDropdown = True Then
            Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! `Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")` did the job. Thank you